# How can I to take an HDMI TV broadcast and overlay text in real time?

Tags: video

Our company wants to be able to have LCD TVs displaying TV with the ability to add an overlay, like a stock ticker at the bottom of the screen, where human resources can add content to be displayed.

I have been trying to nail down the correct terminology for this and come across terms like Keying, Compositing, Live Broadcast Graphics Presentation, and Hardware Overlay but I don't know which of these terms is truly the correct way to refer to what I am trying to do.

[Black Magic](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/decklink/workflow/) offers a product that seems like it can do what I am looking for but their product seems like it is geared for a totally different purpose than what I would be using it for.

[Compix](http://www.compix.tv/products/cynerg2.html) also seems to have a product that would do what I need but again it seems like killing a fly with a sledge hammer.

How can I to take an HDMI TV broadcast and overlay arbitrary content in real time?

Comment: NeTV - http://wiki.chumby.com/index.php/What_is_NeTV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a product that we are working to implement that does everything that we want and more. It is called [iCompel](http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Digital-Signage-Multimedia/Digital-Media-Digital-Signage-Players/iCompel/n-4294957319/p-0) from Black Box and allows you to do a full screen live video stream with other arbitrary zones and layouts superimposed over it with various levels of transparency. The sources for the lays can be powerpoint, HTML, other video source, etc. Pretty amazing product and at a very reasonable price.

Answer (score 2):

I had a simple solution deployed for a videowall purpose before - get a HDMI-capable capture card, and then code a simple HTML ticker that is editable by HR to add/remove content.

Have a computer dedicated to displaying on the LCD TV (with HDMI splitters if so needed), and just have two windows - one of the video (being captured by the HDMI capture card), and the ticker at the bottom. Arrange to suit your aesthetic sense.

Comment: Simple, easy, no software purchase needed.

Comment: That just might work. Is there anywhere I can get the code for the HTML ticker you used or wrote?